# Неправильное склонение "раз" на странице знаков

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На странице знаков пользователя, `Справка` > `Знаки` > `Знаменитый вопрос`, не правильно склоняется слово "раз". Дословно

> получил знак 2 раз

Воспроизвести ситуацию можно например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=274).

Comment: Может просто надо читать, что "получил знак пару раз" :)

Comment: @alexis031182 :D

Comment: Кажется. это часть [вот этого обсуждения](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/)